# DDD - How to form Aggregates where Entities have to reference non-root Entities

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have some Entities and I am trying to follow Domain Driven Design practices to identify Aggregates. I somehow cant do this because I either break the rule of Entities not being allowed to reference non-root Entities of other Aggregates, or I cant form Aggregates at all.

I have the following Entities: Organisation, JobOffer, Candidate, and JobApplication.

- An Organisation creates JobOffers but may only have a limited amount of active JobOffers.
- A Candidate creates JobApplications but may only have a limited amount of active JobApplications.
- A JobApplication references a JobOffer that it is meant for.

Based on that I have to know how many JobOffers an Organisation has before I can create a new one (enforcing limits), I assume Organisation should be an Root-Entity that owns JobOffers. The same applies to Candidates and JobApplications. Now I have two Aggregates: Organisation with JobOffers and Candidate with JobApplications. But... I need to reference JobOffer from JobApplication... and that breaks the rule that I cant reference non-Root-Entities.

[image: Proposed Aggregates with conflict diagram]

I have looked for and found similar questions on this forum but I somehow still cant figure it out, so sorry in advance - I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

I general, you should avoid holding *object* references to other aggregates but rather reference other aggregates by id. In some cases it can be valid to reference some entity within in another aggregate, but again this should be done via id as well.

If you go this way you should ***reference a composite id***. Aggregates are meant to depict ***logical*** boundaries and also ***transactional boundaries***. Child entity ids which are modelled as part of the aggregate only need to be unique inside the boundaries of that aggregate. This makes it a lot easier to focus on stuff just inside those boundaries when performing actions in your system. Even if you are using UUIDs (or GUIDs), if you really need to reference a child entity of another aggregate - let's say you have good reasons for that - you should **model the id graph via the aggregate root** which means always knowing the id of the other aggregate in combination with the id of the entity you are interested in. That means referencing a ***composite id***.

But: whenever I think I need to reference a child entity of another aggregate root at first I investigate this more deeply. This would mean that this child entity might be important as a stand-alone entity as well.

***Did I miss to discover another aggregate root?***

In your case, looking at your domain model diagram, I suspect JobOffer should be an aggregate on its own. Of course I don't know your domain but I can at least guess that there might be some transactions performed in your system allowing to mutate job offers on its own without requiring to consider organization specific business invariants. If this is the case, you should rethink the domain model and consider making **JobOffer an aggregate root on its own**. In this case your initial problem get's resolved automatically. Also note that modelling job offers as aggregates can make actions performed on organizations simpler as well as you do not need to load all the job offers for that organization when loading the organization aggregate. This might of course not be relevant in your case and really depends on the maximum amount of job offers for an organization.

So I think, depending on your business requirements and domain logic invariants I would recommd one of the folllwing two options:

- Reference the foreign child entity only through a composite id including the id of other the aggregate + the child entity id (e.g. by creating some value object that represents this reference as a strong type)
- Make JobOffer an aggregate on its own if the mentioned considerations hold true in your case

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response: It makes a lot of sense!

I am wondering about the JobOffer as aggregate though. Doesnt it have to belong to Organisation where Organisaton is the root? - Because creating new JobOffers requires a check on how many JobOffers the Organisation already has? 

If JobOffer is its own aggregate, then Id have to implement a service for creating JobOffers, which first asks the repository for the total number of JobOffers the Org has, before it allows the creation of a new one. - Would that be the way?

Comment: Also, the same applies to Candidate and JobApplication, since if JobOffer can be its own aggregate there is no reason JobApplication shouldn't be its own aggregate as well?

Comment: The organization aggregate could still keep a list of job offer references (i.e. job offer ids) e.g. via value objects. And then the organization could provide a factory method to create a new job offer instance. This method can also make sure the maximum amount of job offers has not been exceeded and return an error otherwise. Other mutations/changes happening to the job offer could have there own transaction boundary than without needing to consider the organization. But this again depends on your domain logic specifics. The same applies for job application.

Comment: You can have a look at Vaughn Vernon's Implementation of an agile project management application. There a backlog item is an aggregate on it's own although you would say it belongs to a specific project. See https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/domain/model/product/Product.java